# Appending Clones of HTML Form to Document body Respecting IDs

Tags: javascript, html, clone

I have an html form which when signed I'd like to create a number of copies of to display directly after one another. My poor cloning function looks like this:

```
function formCloner(numCopies) {
  let cloneContainer = document.createElement("div");
  cloneContainer.id = "formCopies";
  for(i = 0; i < numCopies) {
    // grab the whole html form
    let html = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]; 
    let htmlClone = html.cloneNode(true);
    /*
     * do some other stuff to the clone
     */
    cloneContainer.appendChild(htmlClone);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(cloneContainer);
}
```

One of the big problems with this approach is that in the end all of the form elements copied over share the same ID. Which is bad. I thought about running through each child node and changing the IDs manually but that seemed like overkill. There must be a simpler answer, can anyone recommend a painless way to achieve the end result of having copies of the form appended to the document body?

Comment: Do you really need the ID of any elements for your app to work? If not, remove entirely and use other methods (event.target, sibling,parent type selectors ) to identify elements when needed. Any event listeners could be assigned via `delegation` so you needn't worry that new DOM nodes will not invoke event handlers

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius IDs are not superfluous at all. They are the only way to link a label with its field using the for attribute.

Comment: How many of those IDs are actually necessary in the first place? Other than for the `for` attribute for `label` elements, IDs aren’t hardly ever absolutely _necessary_ in a form. Newbies tend to treat them like they were the only way to select/access elements in CSS or JS, but they are by far not. So, the easiest way to clone a form without any ID trouble, would be to eliminate IDs :-)

Comment: or in the for loop, set id to `formCopies${i}` for example

Comment: @Salketer - I can see no `label` elements here and a label need not use the Id to associate if the input element is within the label

Comment: There's no label element, but there's no HTML at all displayed in OP, so can only guess if there are. As for nesting input in label, you're right! Even though it doesn't fit all cases, I always forget we can nest them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy... Simple target all elements with IDs, and add _# to them. Also do the same on the for attribute, since they are the only real reason why you'd want to play with IDs in the first place.

```
htmlClone.querySelectorAll("[id]").forEach(elem=>elem.setAttribute('id',elem.getAttribute('id')+"_"+i));
htmlClone.querySelectorAll("[for]").forEach(elem=>elem.setAttribute('for',elem.getAttribute('for')+"_"+i));
```